# setting contact number to edittext in android

Tags: android

I am trying to get the phone number by the code below but setting the number to the **EditText** field seems not to work.

The code in `onActivityResult()` is not giving me the contact name from the selected contacts.

```
EditText number;

public void chooseContact(View v) {

        contact = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.quickContact);
        contact.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);

            }
        });

        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hi contact is selected!!",
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null,
                    null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                id = c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                name = c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if (Integer
                        .parseInt(c.getString(c
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id },
                            null);

                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        cnumber = pCur.getString(pCur
                                .getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cnumber,
                        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        number.setText(cnumber);
                    }

                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: When I toasted the number it gave the number but unable to set it to the edit field

Comment: Are you sure the value you are getting is a string only try by inserting any other string value to check in `number.setText(cnumber)`something like `number.setText("cnumber")` or `number.setText("Number"+cnumber` something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
number.setText(cnumber+"");
```

or

```
number.setText(String.valueOf(cnumber));
```

Updates:

Change your logic

```
int i = 0;
while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    cnumber = pCur.getString(pCur
                            .getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cnumber,
                    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if(i == 0){
                    number.setText(cnumber);
                    break;
                    }
               }
```

here. Because this loop will set the last number only in your `number` edittext.

Comment: This worked out for me but only one contact number is getting selected into the edit text field no other contacts are getting selected!! I mean when i added new contacts it is not selecting the new contact numbers...only selecting for old contact!!

Comment: no it isnt working the application is stopping unfortunately!!

Comment: no @Gunaseelan .....it is not even taking other numbers except one contact that was previously stored!!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't find your `EditText` in the code, `number = findViewById(R.id.edittext)`, try finding and executing it.

Answer (score -1):

It's also showing the error. So, to solve -

### 1.

```
id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
//Instead of this place String keyword at starting.
```

### 2.

```
cnumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
//Place String keyword at starting.
```

### 3.

```
name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
//Place String keyword at starting.
```